# Dictionary wont get update

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am using an existing dictionary:

```
my_dict = {a: [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]}
```

*example

and I have defying a func that gets a new keys and values to my_dict:

```
def adding_new():
    my_dict[new_key] = [(7,8,9)]
```

i need the dict to update and be saved in my program, but it keeps staying the same as started.
any suggestions?

edit:
Actually I get why you answer that, im pretty sure im not asking my question right.. im new at python and english isnt my spoken language
What im asking is why when i call my function, I dont see any changes in my code? I mean, is there any way to make my program to make changes in my existing code?

Comment: Can you improve the formatting?

I think in the second line you want to remove the square brackets. As for the key you want to set the value to a set, not an array of sets. Like `def adding_new(): my_dict[new_key] = (7,8,9)`

Comment: There are a lot of problems. What exactly do you want here, a dictionary that contains sets?

Comment: Please consider to (re-) do a basic Python tutorial – ``a: [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]`` is not a dictionary, amongst other problems. Try to construct a [mcve] to allow both you and us to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell from your code..

But I think your main problem is that you are just defining a function and not calling the function.

First I fixed the syntax of your code:

```
my_dict = {"a": (1,2,3), "b": (4,5,6)}


def adding_new():
    my_dict["new_key"] = (7,8,9)
```

Secondly I add a call of the fuction you defined:

```
my_dict = {"a": (1,2,3), "b": (4,5,6)}


def adding_new():
    my_dict["new_key"] = (7,8,9)

adding_new()
```